# Definition of Tensors Over Complex Numbers

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

My question is two part. First, how does the definition of tensors and tensor spaces change when the vectors that the tensors act upon are elements of a complex vector space as apposed to when they are elements of a real vector space? For example the dot product is bilinear when operating on real vectors, but it becomes antilinear in the second argument when applied to complex vectors. Is there a nice generalization of this kind of change when talking about complex vector spaces?

Second, is there any known application of tensors when generalized to complex vector spaces?

My background: I am going to be a sophomore in college next year, majoring in applied mathematics. I have some background in proof based linear algebra.

Comment: The definition of tensor products does not change. They are defined in the same way over any commutative ring instead of $\mathbb{R}$. As for the dot product, there are two different ones over $\mathbb{C}$: a bilinear one and one that is antilinear in the second argument (and I bet some authors use one that is antilinear in the first argument); both of them have their uses, and none of them is "the right definition".

Comment: @darijgrinberg Isn't the dot product technically a tensor? Wouldn't allowing tensors to be linear in some arguments and antilinear in others be inconsistent with the requirement for them to be linear in the first place?

Comment: The bilinear dot product can be seen as a tensor in $V^\ast \otimes V^\ast$ (where $V = \mathbb{C}^n$). The sesquilinear dot product can be seen as a tensor in $V^\ast \otimes \overline{V^\ast}$, where for every $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $W$, we let $\overline{W}$ be the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $W$ "twisted by complex conjugation" (i.e., $\overline{W} = W$ as additive groups, but $\lambda v$ in $\overline{W}$ means $\overline{\lambda} v$ in $W$).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Ah that makes sense.